# Confusion with parallel construction of the infinitives "to acknowledge" and "to accept"

Tags: infinitives, parallelism

In the following sentences, the parallel construction of the infinitives "to acknowledge" and "to accept" have, at least temporarily, befuddled me. Should it be

> To acknowledge the equality of black folks would also, so it was believed, accept a lowered status for rural whites.

OR

> To acknowledge the equality of black folks would be also, so it was believed, to accept a lowered status for rural whites.

Comment: You might want to review your word order in your second alternative.

Comment: Acknowledgement of the equality of black folks would also, it was believed, indicate the acceptance of a lowered status for rural whites.

Comment: I like using "indicate" to avoid the difficulty; I don't like using a noun, "acknowledgement", to indicate an action.

Comment: I have reviewed it, IA, to a state of befuddlement! Rescue me!

Comment: The parallelism is clearer in the rewrite 'To acknowledge the equality of black folks would also, so it was believed, be to accept a lowered status for rural whites.' << To do A would also be to do B. >>

Comment: _Be also_ in the second sentence should be _also be_. Otherwise, it's fine, though the first one is muddled.

Answer (score 1):

Taking bracketed adjunct and supplement out of the first sentence given

> To acknowledge the equality of black folks
>
> would [also],
>
> [so it was believed],
>
> accept a lowered status for rural whites.

we have:

> To acknowledge the equality of black folks would accept a lowered
>   status for rural whites.

simplify with demonstratives and take out the auxiliary:

> To acknowledge this accepts that

so, in grammatical terms the question would be:

**Is a *to*-infinitival subject allowed for the verb *accept*?**

There is at least one other example of a similar construction out in the wild:

> To hold otherwise would accept that the parties were diligent enough
>   to account for whatever inflation may exist up until the lease began,
>   but, for no understandable reason, completely ignored the decades of
>   inflation that would occur after the lease began.
>
> Hardin St. Marine LLC v. Kenova Terminal Co., CIVIL ACTION NO.
>   3:18-1181, 7 (S.D.W. Va. May. 22, 2019)

For the second sentence:

> To acknowledge the equality of black folks would be to accept a
>   lowered status for rural whites.

Simplified:

> To acknowledge this is to accept that.

The structure here is:

[*to*-infinitival] *be* [*to*-infinitival]

This structure is fairly common and seems like the clear choice between the two.

Comment: I agree-- first version leaves out necessary parts; the second is (I thought) adequately constructed. As a devoted sentence diagram-er, I could find no fault. However, it may be that, in the words of my mentor, "I don't see anything incorrect there, it's just rather vulgar." (i.e, not elegantly constructed) The most neglected aspect of writing, and the teaching of writing, is what mental activities are involved in the revision process, and the best revision methods. I believe that at least 50% of errors occur during revision-- a change meant to improve that leaves another, inadvertent, error.

Answer (score 0):

Group X was loath to acknowledge the equality of black people since, they believed, doing so would lead to a lowered status for rural whites.